# Print crystal report without using the default print button

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I have an application(ASP.NET), in that I am showing different reports using the crystal report viewer.The deafult print dialog is not matching with the template I used in the page.so decided to make a differnt one.The Export option is dynamically working and exporting the report, but for printing,I use the printToPrinter method, which is not showing up the print dialog where I can seleted the printer and the print quality, paper orientation..etc...

Can anyone suggest a method to invoke the print dialog through this method

Answer (score 1):

In order to configure these parameters in your code you can use:

```
string printerName = ""; //Insert printer name here.
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();
rpt.PrintOptions.PrinterName = printerName;
rpt.PrintOptions.PaperOrientation = PaperOrientation.Landscape;
```

And so on... I think that all the rest of your needed configuration are there, available for you to set.